# How to use local-only dependencies in PNPM workspace

Tags: monorepo, pnpm, turborepo, pnpm-workspace

I have a general PNPM question regarding Monorepos. Let me describe a simplified problem statement:

Monorepo contains two packages: `foo@1.0.0` and `bar@1.0.0`

- The `foo` package is a library which is published to NPM
- The `bar` package is a private library which is not published to NPM. There is no need for it to be published since it will not be consumed by end-users
- `foo` depends on `bar`
- `foo` uses the Workspace protocol to link to `bar`, ie. `"bar": "workspace: *"`
- Locally, everything runs great. But when I publish `foo`, `bar` will try to point to an external package on the NPM registry. What I want to happen is for bar to be bundled with foo. I have tried using [bundledDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#bundleddependencies), but without any luck.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved? I could publish `bar` to NPM as a private package, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: If `bar` is a private package, why do you want to publish its source code with a public package? It automatically becomes public then.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use npm packages in an unconventional way. You need to publish both foo and bar to the registry. If you think bar is not useful as a separate package, then don't make it a separate package.

Comment: @ZoltanKochan yes you're right I realized I was thinking about this the wrong way. I ended up making all the packages public